# Can we reach the end of time in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I mean I wait 24 hours about 20 times to get lots of money from my spouse but I'm wondering if I reach a certain date... will the game be over ?

Is there a date limit in this game or we can play till the end of time ?

Comment: It ends after day 3. You can play the song of time in reverse to get a bit more time.

Comment: Where's the Ocarina ??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They specifically advertise the game as being able to be played forever because of its infinite quests, so yes, you can play until the end of time.

Comment: [Obligatory TVTropes link.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakeYourTime)

Answer (score 22):

No, the game will not end at a certain date. In 200 game-years your character will be his young spruce self and everything will be just as urgent as it was.

Comment: +1 for "just as urgent". I love it that in Skyrim (and previous Elder Scrolls titles and Fallout and ...) they always tell you "You  must *immediately* go to *Sometown* and *do-heroic-deed*". When in fact you can go around half the world, save 5 other towns from evil demons and usurpers (or become any of the two) and *then* come back to *do-heroic-deed* and it will still be soon enough.